# ListView freaks out when I try to update the ArrayAdapter, is the header?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this ListView that is using an array adapter:

```
//global
ArrayList<Location> locations=new ArrayList<Location>(); //array list of location objects
ArrayAdapter<Location> theLocations;
ListView listView;
```

then in onCreateView of my Fragment:

```
    theLocations = new ArrayAdapter<Location>(mContext, 
          R.layout.location_row, locations);
    listView.setAdapter(theLocations);
```

This works pretty well I think, though if I try to update this adapter it freaks out...

```
//in my fragment, another dialog makes this call here to update the list.
public void onUIUpdate(Location l) { //listener call back when dialog "ok" clicked
    locations.add(l); //it is okay with this.
    theLocations.notifyDataSetChanged(); //dies
}
```

It dies with the error:

`07-23 08:03:28.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`

does that mean it doesn't like the Location in the ArrayAdapter ???  does this mean I have to make my own custom listadapter?  If I don't call theLocations.notifyDataSetChanged() everything is okay but then nothing updates... :(

I should note that the toString() in the Location class is override to return a String name;

after a comment I tried this:

```
public void onUIUpdate(Location l) {
    locations.add(l);
    //theLocations.notifyDataSetChanged();
    WrapperListAdapter wr = (WrapperListAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter aa=(ArrayAdapter)wr.getWrappedAdapter();
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

LOL no luck here, was a stab in the dark.  Also wandering if its the addHeaderView I used on the ListView?  I am not sure if it makes it immutable in the future using addHeaderView?

Comment: Man I had zero joy with this all weekend, I cannot believe this is that difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment about ListView design, it is very ugly, but I do listView.getAdapter().getWrappedAdapter().notifyDataSetChabged(); and it works.

Comment: hmm I don't even have a getWrappedAdapter() method..do i need a double cast?  It has listView.getAdapter() and that was about it, makes me nervous how ugly the design is.

Comment: puzzled by how that works, they claim listView returns ListAdapter(), of which the only methods are: `isEnabled` and `areAllItemsEnabled` :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html  and it inherits from Adapter as far as I can tell which does not have the getWrappedAdapter().